Blender viewport 1 to 1 in real world
This might be a silly question but how do I get 1 to 1 scale in blender 4.1 viewport with real life ruler on the monitor?
I made a cylinder 10 cm long, but when I meassure it it's 10.4 or something. I try zooming in and out but the viewport grid snapped to the side is never 1cm to 1cm
There is some option named "Zoom Camera 1:1" but it's not selectable
Basically what I mean that this grin ON SCREEN

NEVER measures 1cm when I measure it with a real life RULER pressed against the MONITOR. It's always a measure off

Not really sure what you mean by "real life ruler on the monitor". Can you add an image of what you're looking to measure? You'll see different results depending on whether you're in Orthographic or Perspective view (5 key on the numpad).

To quote some old movie "I mean it"
I pushed a ruler against the screen of a monitor to measure 10 cm, and the cylinder that I've set to be 10 cm long is 10.5 cm long while using orthographic view

Simple answer is that you can't! It will depend on your monitor dimensions, resolution and screen size and the size of Blender's own window among other things.

Just as @JohnEason said, you cannot get it matched, it depends on many different factors. Or, of course it might  happen that you accidentally manage to get it matched with real life measurements, but that will be coincidental. You cannot deliberately set it to be like that. And should this be saved in a file? Let's say you create it on a 32" 4k screen, someone else opens it with a 32" 2k screen... and another one with a 27". Even with two monitors of the same nominal size, the pixels can have different sizes between manufacturers and product lines.

I might even be tempted to believe that there exist standardized calibrated monitors that are designed to show matching real measurements and some kind of CAD software etc. that can make use of it, but Blender is not CAD software and if you do not have a specialized monitor I do not see how this should work.

Well that's unfortunate. I thought it could've been as easy as putting the dimensions of the monitor somewhere, even if it's temporary settings. I don't know a lot of people that use multiple monitors to work 3d stuff and often change between them. Don't monitors interface with the computer and provide info like physical dimensions? Anyways I suppose it can't be helped. Thank you all for the replies.

To be honest I can't think of any reason why I would want to see an exact sized model on screen in Blender which as @GordonBrinkmann says might possibly be used occasionally with CAD software, but Blender isn't designed that way and hopefully never will be.

"I don't know a lot of people that use multiple monitors to work 3d stuff" - seriously? Lots and lots of people use multiple monitors especially to work with 3d. Maybe less so when 4K(and higher) resolution monitors became a thing, but it's actually very common. 3d is one area that benefits from it, because you might need to work with a lot of stuff at the same time - multiple views, various reference, multiple editors, multiple programs... I used to always have 2 monitors before 4K became popular, now it's enough for me personally, but lot's of professionals do still use multiple monitors...

@GlennCarver The monitor provides information like the (nominal) diagonal width in the same way it provides the model name - it is completely irrelevant for displaying an image on it. The operation system, graphics card need to know things like resolution, frequency etc., but if the monitor display shows 1920 × 1080 on a 24", 27" or 32" screen and how large actual pixels are is neither communicated nor in any way relevant to the system.

This is obviously too arbitrary and practically never needed in normal circumstances to have dedicated features, but you could change your view or camera focal length(or orthographic scale in case of orthographic camera), or move the camera until whatever you have matches the ruler:


Since you can enter values manually, you can make the adjustments as small as you want.
Like Gordon Brinkmann indicates in the comments, it's really easy to mess things up once you have this, so it might be a good idea to tear a separate window with only a viewport and keep it constant size on screen(maybe maximized). It would of course be difficult to work in it while keeping it the same size, but a separate window can be minimized while working in the main Blender window.



Well yes, but as we told him in the comments, you might get something that mostly matches reality... but an accidental slight scrolling the wheel in the viewport or a minimal adjustment of the window size and all these adjustments were in vain. So there is no way to keep it or switch between "normal" work mode where you can zoom in and out as you might need for editing and then back to "real size". Sure you can press Numpad 0 to go in and out of camera view, but you can easily change the size of the camera window intentionally or accidentally. There is no "zoom lock" or something like that.

I assume, they are aware of this. But yes, mentioning that is probably a good idea even if it should be obvious that if you zoom in or out, it's not going to work. One can have a separate viewport(and even window) from the ones they work in. If we are talking about the obvious, then it's probably also worth mentioning that 3d viewports and cameras(other than orthographic) display stuff with perspective and parts of the scene are smaller or bigger depending on it. It's one weird question.... But it's possible to match the sizes in a limited way.

As for accidents...  :D  I will assume, the OP doesn't accidentally fall out of the window and die making this all effort useless... We usually ignore stuff like accidentally spilling coffee on one's keyboard, lightning strikes and shark attacks while answering questions, so this should be the same, the way I see it. :D

I don't know how you came to people falling out of windows and dying :D I mean accidents like moving into the 3D Viewport window accidentally scrolling the mouse wheel and oops, size has changed. Or thinking, I don't need that Timeline window so large, make it a little bit smaller - and so the 3D Viewport gets a little larger, the size changes as well... things like that which happen all the time intentionally or unintentionally while editing when you don't have to care about size. I also think it limits modeling cars, characters, landscapes a lot when they have to fit your monitor :D

I imagine in some specific design process, people may want to see things real scale on the monitor. In that scenario one might have a separate dedicated always maximized window with a viewport that they have measured  and zoomed to match real scale on the monitor. It would obviously need to be left untouched while working in the main Blender window, but it can be minimized when working and opened only when one needs to see things real scale. In that scenario, one shuold be careful not to zoom or orbit in it... Why? I have no idea. A bit more context would definitely benefit the question.
